# Docusign Access Code Verification- Custom Message in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

When creating an envelope in Docusign using the REST API's, you have the option of passing an access code and when the recipient receives the email via the link, they are required to enter this code directly in docusign. Is it possible to edit the default message that is shown to the end user in docusign?

IE instead of the default:
The sender has requested you enter a secret access code prior to reviewing the document. You should have received an access code in a separate communication. Please enter the code and validate it in order to proceed to viewing the document.

I would like it to say something like:
Please enter your birth date in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for using DocuSign! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You need to modify the Signing resource XML file under your Branding in DocuSign. You can find more details at [SigningResourceFile](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/DocuSign-Signing-Resource-File(v2.0).pdf), check page# 16 which explain how to change the Text on the Authentication Request screen.